# How to enlarge an Image in grid View when selected

Tags: java, android

I want to enlarge my Image when it is selected.
My problem is Image is selected, but not enlargened.

I have tried many things like enlarge imageView in XML but no work.

You will see below the code for image selection:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.mImageNone = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_none);
            holder.mImageNone.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.mImageViewSelected = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_selected);
            holder.mImageViewSelected.setOnClickListener(this);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        GridViewData data = mImagePath.get(position);
        holder.mImageNone.setTag(data);
        holder.mImageViewSelected.setTag(data);
        if (data.getSelected()) {
            holder.mImageViewSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.mImageViewSelected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

and the next part of this is

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.image: {


                    break;
                }
                case R.id.image_none: {
                    GridViewData data = (GridViewData) v.getTag();
    //
                    if (data.getSelected()) {
                        data.setSelcted(false);
                    } else {
                        data.setSelcted(true);
                    }

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.image_selected: {
                    GridViewData data = (GridViewData) v.getTag();

                    if (data.getSelected()) {
                        data.setSelcted(false);
                    } else {
                        data.setSelcted(true);
                    }

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
```

Comment: I hope you are looking for `Continuous Shared Element Transitions`
below link will help you https://github.com/google/android-transition-examples/tree/master/GridToPager

Comment: thanks. but i want some changes in my code so it will give the result.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this in to your onClickListener:
`imageView.animate().scaleX(1.1).scaleY(1.1f)`

// it means when you select this image it will be enlarged. Replace imageview with your Imageview name

and in ViewHolder view bind method don't forger to add 'if, else' check for checking if it is selected and setting scale for selected items.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. This reads like you read the question title and answered directly, without reading the OP's code. Please suggest the OP where to actually put this in their code, since they posted it in the first place.